# Hidden characters in a std::string? string.length() is returning more than expected

Tags: c++, string, append, string-length

Writing a homework problem where I encode any char (e.g. number, letter or punctuation), to its pre-supplied 'braille' string format (e.g. 'x' == "0.00.0").

I have decided to encode each char by declaring an empty string and appending this string (using += operator) with the relevant 'braille' code, using helper functions shown below:

```
string braille_ = "";

  if(isdigit(ch))
    encode_digit(ch, braille_);
  else if(ispunct(ch))
    encode_punctuation(ch, braille_);
  else if(isalpha(ch))
    encode_letter(ch, braille_);
  else
    braille_ = "......";
```

When I pass (for example) the letter 'Z' and the string by reference to the function below, it appends '|' to the string followed by ".....0|" (because it isupper) followed by "0.0.00" (the code for 'z').

```
void encode_letter(char ch, string& braille)
{
  braille += '|';

  if(isupper(ch)){
    braille += ".....0";
    ch = tolower(ch);
  }

  if(ch == 'a')
    braille += "0.....";
  else if(ch == 'b')
    braille += "00....";
```

...

```
 else if(ch == 'x')
   braille == "0.00.0";
 else if(ch == 'y')
   braille += "0.0000";
 else if(ch == 'z')
   braille += "0.0.00";
```

My problem: When I cout the resulting string I get "|.....0|0.0.00". **I count 14 characters in that string, yet when I do string.length() it returns 17**. It appears that there are some hidden characters in there which don't show up when I print the string, but which add to its length.

This is happening across the board where I append to the string several times. Can anyone tell me what is going on? What are these hidden characters, if they exist at all? I'm not looking for an alternative method (I know there are many), I just want to understand the behaviour

**EDIT: I have isolated the problem to when I use the += operator twice over as below. Minimal reproducible example:**

```
string braille_ = "";
encode_letter('H', braille_);

void encode_letter(char ch, string& encoded)
{
  size_t before = encoded.length();

  encoded += ".....0|";
  encoded += "00..0.|";

  size_t after = encoded.length();

  cout << ch << " = " << encoded << " with length growing from " << before <<
  " to " << after << endl;

}
```

Expected output:

H = .....0|00..0.| with length growing from 0 to **14**

Actual output:

H = .....0|00..0.| with length growing from 0 to **17**

Comment: Try looking at your source code with a hex-editor, do the string actually contain the contents you believe it does? You haven't by mistake added some invisible characters in the literals themselves? If not, then please try to create a [mcve] which replicates the problem, and which we could try out ourselves by simply copy-pasting it.

Comment: Thank you, I have now isolated the problem to when the += operator is used more than once on a pass-by-ref string. Please see minimal reproducible example above.

Comment: I just [can't replicate it](https://godbolt.org/z/c5P5EA). Either you have a very weird and unknown bug in your compiler or standard library implementation, or you do something that you forget to show us.